# Implementation of WAE-GAN does not match with the description in the paper

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoders, generative-models, wasserstein

According to the litterature and specifically to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.01558), the wasserstein autoencoders is an encoder-decoder architecture. So it must contain encoder and decoder parts.

in the algorithm description of GAN-based WAN, in the requirements, there were initialization of encoder, decoder and latent discriminator.

In parallel, I saw many implementations of GAN based WAE on github in tensorflow, there were all implemented through a discrminator and generator parts. No autoencoder architecture. So my question, are those implementations correspond to another architecture beside the WAE-GAN ? or maybe I didn't understand the connection between the paper and the implementation.

Here you will find some links for implementation:

[implementation 1](https://github.com/schelotto/Wasserstein_Autoencoders/blob/master/wae_gan.py)
[implementation 2](https://github.com/kpandey008/wasserstein-gans/blob/master/WGAN.ipynb)
[implementation 3](https://github.com/wiseodd/generative-models/blob/master/GAN/improved_wasserstein_gan/wgan_gp_tensorflow.py)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, There is Wasserstein-GAN which is a GAN network but uses the wasserstein distance to calculate the loss. So, it has the discriminator and generator networks. The [implementation 2](https://github.com/kpandey008/wasserstein-gans/blob/master/WGAN.ipynb) and [implementation 3](https://github.com/wiseodd/generative-models/blob/master/GAN/improved_wasserstein_gan/wgan_gp_tensorflow.py) correspond to that network.

However, my target was the Wasserstein autoencoders which has encoder, decoder and discriminator parts. The [implementation 1](https://github.com/schelotto/Wasserstein_Autoencoders/blob/master/wae_gan.py) corresponds to Wasserstein autoencoders and not to Wasserstein GAN.

It was confusing for me.